# SPS 2007 backup webparts etc

Tags: backup, sharepoint-2007, webpart

I would like to backup my hole Share-point 2007 stuff. But as I read on http://searchwinit.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid1_gci1319629,00.html Share-point isn't able to backup all content for an disaster restore. Following can't be backuped

```
* Third-party or custom Web parts
* SharePoint site definitions and XML files
* SharePoint .aspx template pages
* SharePoint script files
```

Know I want to know how can I backup these items, especially web parts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah....

Carefull...

- Web parts are NOT CONTENT. It is not about the data of the web part - it is about the INSTALLED PART CODE. This is not part of a content librqary. These are normally INSTALLED (with an MSI file) and then activated for a site.
- Similar to Site definitions, templates and script files. They are note stored in the content database.

So, a normal backup backs up a SITE etc. - the database end. But the installation is naturally not covered by sharepoint.

Comment: Furthermore, when you backup and restore a site, all the features webparts and solutions need to be reinstalled. I would export your webparts (saves the configuration) of all your webparts that are not duplicates,  and import them after you restore the site and reinstall the webpart solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For web parts, you need to make sure that you keep track of what web parts have been installed, and in a disaster scenario, you re-install them (after re-installing SharePoint, but before restoring your content).

For the other things - any changes you make to the SharePoint 12 hive (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12`) or to the IIS root for your sites need to be backed up at the filesystem level. In a disaster situation you can then restore the customized files (again, probably after SharePoint install, but before content restore) and you should be good to go.

Mentioning the IIS roots also reminded me - you can also dump the configuration of your web sites and application pools from IIS so that you can re-import them after a rebuild. This is far easier than having to remember any IIS-level customizations you may have done.